# Filtering elevation changes in time on a point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, elevation, cross-section, elevation-profile

I have a point layer extracted from a GPX file that contains a series of points representing elevation and time, as on the following image:
[image: attribute table]

This huge amount of points means that, in many cases, the elevation will be the same in many different fields that are separated by merely seconds, as seen on the previous image.

The goal is to create an **elevation profile**. Because of the aforementioned issue, the elevation profile created looks as follows, displaying those unnatural *valleys*.
[image]

In order to avoid them, firstly I just thought of deleting manually all the values represented after any elevation change. Again in the first image, rows 25 to 29 would be deleted, 30 and 31 would stay, then 32 to 38 deleted, and so on. The problem of this method, obviously, is that there are around 17000 rows.

Is there any way to automate this? Or is there any way to *average* the elevation changes, softening the slopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression should do it when using within "select by expression". It selects features where the previous feature within a group has the same elevation value.

```sql
-- Only check within the same track_seg_id group
attribute(get_feature(@layer,'uid',"uid"-1),'track_seg_id')
=
"track_seg_id"
and(
 -- Check if the previous feature has the same elevation
 attribute(get_feature(@layer,'uid',"uid"-1),'ele')
 =
 "ele"
 -- Or is the first feature within a group
 or
 "track_seg_point_id"=1 -- change this to whatever indicates the very first feature within a group
)
```

What you need:

- A unique group id, as you have in your field `track_seg_id`. This group id may have gaps and can be of any type, such as integer, string, date, ....
- A numeric UID field with no gaps. No gaps is the reason why I recommend to not simply use `$id`. The UID field needs to be ordered 1. by your groups (`track_seg_id`) and 2. by the order within these groups (`track_seg_point_id`). To create the ID, order your attribute table by these condtitions and then use `@row_number` to create the id. This UID is required so you can make use of `get_feature()` and be able to grab the previous feature during iteration (which is what the field calculator actually does).

Example selection:

[image]

Then you can simply hit the delete button or do whatever you like.